# How to plot string type Numpy array with Seaborn?

Tags: python, numpy, seaborn

I am trying to plot the following array:

```
array(['2019-08-23 16:24:55.000', '2019-08-23 15:51:07.000',
       '2019-08-23 15:41:30.000', '2019-08-23 15:36:45.000',
       '2019-08-23 13:54:36.000', '2019-08-23 11:32:04.000',
       '2019-08-23 11:15:20.000', '2019-08-23 11:07:46.000',
       '2019-08-23 10:51:20.000', '2019-08-23 10:51:19.000',
       '2019-08-23 10:33:24.000', '2019-08-23 09:50:18.000',
       '2019-08-23 08:21:51.000', '2019-08-22 11:50:55.000',
       '2019-08-22 11:36:52.000', '2019-08-22 11:31:24.000',
       '2019-08-22 09:56:18.000', '2019-08-21 21:42:50.000',
       '2019-08-21 21:11:08.000', '2019-08-21 21:09:18.000',
       '2019-08-21 21:04:52.000', '2019-08-21 20:57:57.000',
       '2019-08-21 20:27:09.000', '2019-08-21 20:06:50.000',
       '2019-08-21 20:01:00.000', '2019-08-21 19:50:41.000',
       '2019-08-21 17:53:00.000', '2019-08-21 17:38:45.000',
       '2019-08-21 16:37:32.000', '2019-08-15 14:04:18.000',
       '2019-08-15 13:42:21.000', '2019-08-15 13:36:25.000',
       '2019-08-15 13:27:50.000', '2019-08-15 13:22:55.000'], dtype='<U23')
```

```
sns.distplot(nx)
```

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     73             is_float16_result = True
     74 
---> 75     ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     76     if isinstance(ret, mu.ndarray):
     77         ret = um.true_divide(

TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Is there a way to plot such array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully sure of what you try to do, but I would say you need to convert your array to representative integers then you can plot. So convert to datetime and then integer:

```
sns.distplot(nx.astype('datetime64[s]').astype('int'))
```

[image]

Now if you want to have the date back to the x-axis, maybe do:

```
g = sns.distplot(nx.astype('datetime64[s]').astype('int'))
g.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks().astype('datetime64[s]').astype('datetime64[D]'), rotation=20)
```

[image]